# how to redirect another page with select list value on button click in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

i have select list values.after any change in select list and click on Button (it have to redirect the page number i have mentioned with select list value changed).
what i have done so far.

take another item P213_CLASS_TYPE_VAL

create DA on select list

```
Select :P213_CLASS_TYPE into :P213_CLASS_TYPE_VAL from dual;
item to submit : P213_CLASS_TYPE,P213_CLASS_TYPE_VAL
item to return : P213_CLASS_TYPE_VAL;
```

Button Action: Redirect to Page in this Application
Page 218

```
Set Item 
Name                   Value
P218_GET_CLASS_TYPE    &P213_CLASS_TYPE_VAL.
```

the issue we face is, some it redirect with changed item value and some time redirect with previous item value

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a dynamic action to redirect to another page, that is a common mistake and unnecessarily complicates things.
The easiest way to do this is to have the button submit the page and create a branch to page 218 where you pass the value of P213_CLASS_TYPE_VAL.

On page 213: Button with action: "Submit Page"

On page 213: 
Branch to page 218 with:

- Server-side condition: "When Button Pressed" = your button.
- Behavior: Page or URL(Redirect), page 281 and Set Items P218_GET_CLASS_TYPE to &P213_CLASS_TYPE_VAL.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: When you use a DA to pass data to another page the values never reach the session. But when you submit the form, the data is sent it to the session. You can validate the session using the button located in the bottom bar.